# Epson SureColor F7070 & Wasatch 7.0 Issues -- Large Format Printer Only Printing a Few Inches, then "Media Out"

Tags: printing, printer

I work for a small business. We had an emergency and one of the only employees who knows how to do this is out.

*What*: We have an **Epson SureColor F7070** printer and **Wasatch Version 7.0**. We're printing from a machine with Windows 7.

*What's Happening*: is that the printer will yield the first four or five inches of the print. It then cuts out and says "Media Out." This is untrue as there's quite a lot of paper in the machine.

*What We've Done*: We have reset the media settings, and we've also pretty much read the Epson manual cover to cover without any luck. We have tried several different files and jobs with the same result.

*Tech Support*: We called Epson, and they said it was a problem with Wasatch. Only -- Wasatch's customer service number (we called 3h ago) goes to a voice mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by JYA of T-shirt Forums website:

"Do you leave the paper in the machine all night long without releasing the tension? Turn your printer off and release the tension. Pull the paper through and cut the first 4-6 inches off, all the way across the width of the paper.Turn on the printer, load your paper up, and it should work fine."